# Version History in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history

I am currently looking to manually move one document from a document library to another document library on the same site collection. When I do this will the version history come over when it is moved or will I lose this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't lose it. When we use "Move to" function to move one document from a document library to another document library on the same site collection, it will retain its previous version history.